# Trouble with command line execution or R script file from within Python shell

Tags: python, r, shell, ubuntu

I'm currently using the `optparse` package cast an R script file as a command line executable file that accepts C-style long and short flags. The program is running on Ubuntu. The execution of the overall application is controlled by a Python script that (1) first uses `os.system` to call `chmod` on the `script.R` file as follows:

```
import os 
os.system("chmod +x script.R; export PATH=$PATH:`pwd`")
```

I then attempt to execute the program, again from within Python using `os.system` as follows:

```
program_call = "script.R --arg1 1"
os.system(program_call)
```

This returns the error:

```
sh: 1: script.R: not found
32512
```

The really puzzling thing is that this was working fine just a day ago and now it's erroring out. I'm developing this application with several other people, so I'm wondering if this could be caused by a change in my administrative permissions. I've verified that all necessary file are contained within the current working directory.

Comment: So far the best I've come up with is to rm -rf the git repo, re-clone it, and shut down all but one terminal window. for some reason this works and the program stops throwing the error. still no idea why this was happening in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change to the `PATH` environment variable in your first call to `os.system` won't carry over to the second call, since it's a separate shell process.  If you instead modify `PATH` within Python, it should work.  Try

```
os.environ['PATH'] += ":" + os.getcwd()
os.system("chmod +x script.R")
program_call = "script.R --arg1 1"
os.system(program_call)
```